# edge or line tracking

Tags: tracking

I have footage of a forward dolly on a door with no identifying markers. By the middle of the shot, the top corners of the door are out of frame, and the bottom corners are never in frame.

[image]

I can see the side edges start to finish, however. So I keyed out the door to create a sharper contrast with the walls.

[image]

With the sharp contrast between the blue door and white walls, can blender track the edges of the door and create a plane? Line segment tracking or edge tracking? Does it exist in blender?

Comment: What is your end goal? A mask to composite out the door or points in the 3dview for objects to move with the camera? The corners of the door aren't your only options, for other tracking points you have the picture frames, the door handle and lock as well as the hinge, peep hole and light switch. Which of these stays in the entire shot?

Comment: Blender Guru mentions a software in this tutorial: http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/render-onto-photo-background/

Comment: Shady, The add-on you're talking about is stuffmatic's Blam, and although it's a cool add-on, it looks like it's only for modeling an object based on a photo. My end goal was to motion track a callbox on the wall, but I lost markers as the shot progressed and never had enough markers to get good tracking data. As I found out, I can use trackers that don't track start to finish. Here's a link to the video    https://youtu.be/3teHs27E2Ys